# cannot readsample from IMFSource in synchronous mode

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I am having trouble with a video recording application that I am writing using Microsoft Media Foundation.

Specifically, the read/write function (which I put on a loop that lives on it's own thread) doesn't make it pass the call to `ReadSample`:

```
HRESULT WinCapture::rwFunction(void) {

    HRESULT hr;
    DWORD streamIndex, flags;
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp;
    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;

    EnterCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
    // Read another sample.
    hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
        0,
        &streamIndex,   // actual
        &flags,//NULL,   // flags
        &llTimeStamp,//NULL,   // timestamp
        &pSample    // sample
        );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

    hr = m_pWriter->WriteSample(0, pSample);

    goto done;

done:
    return hr;
    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
}
```

The value of hr is an exception code: `0xc00d3704` so the code snippet skips the call to `WriteSample`.

It is a lot of steps, but I am fairly certain that I am setting up `m_pReader` (type `IMFSource *`) correctly.

```
HRESULT WinCapture::OpenMediaSource(IMFMediaSource *pSource)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IMFAttributes *pAttributes = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 2);


    // use a callback
    //if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    //{
    //  hr = pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, this);
    //}

    // set the desired format type
    DWORD dwFormatIndex = (DWORD)formatIdx;

    IMFPresentationDescriptor *pPD = NULL;
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSD = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pHandler = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pType = NULL;

    // create the source reader
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(
            pSource,
            pAttributes,
            &m_pReader
            );
    }

    // steps to set the selected format type
    hr = pSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pPD);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    BOOL fSelected;
    hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(0, &fSelected, &pSD);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(dwFormatIndex, &pType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
        NULL,
        pType
        );

    // set to maximum framerate?
    hr = pHandler->GetCurrentMediaType(&pType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the maximum frame rate for the selected capture format.

    // Note: To get the minimum frame rate, use the 
    // MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN attribute instead.

    PROPVARIANT var;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pType->GetItem(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, &var)))
    {
        hr = pType->SetItem(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, var);

        PropVariantClear(&var);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);
        {
            goto done;
        }

        hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            NULL,
            pType
            );
    }




    goto done;

done:
    SafeRelease(&pPD);
    SafeRelease(&pSD);
    SafeRelease(&pHandler);
    SafeRelease(&pType);
    SafeRelease(&pAttributes);
    return hr;
}
```

This code is all copied from Microsoft documentation pages and the SDK sample code. The variable `formatIdx` is 0, I get it from enumerating the camera formats and choosing the first one.

UPDATE

I have rewritten this program so that it uses callbacks instead of a blocking read/write function and I have exactly the same issue.

Here I get the device and initiate the callback method:

```
HRESULT WinCapture::initCapture(const WCHAR *pwszFileName, IMFMediaSource *pSource) {

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    EncodingParameters params;
    params.subtype = MFVideoFormat_WMV3; // TODO, paramterize this
    params.bitrate = TARGET_BIT_RATE;
    m_llBaseTime = 0;
    IMFMediaType *pType = NULL;
    DWORD sink_stream = 0;

    EnterCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
    hr = m_ppDevices[selectedDevice]->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSource));
    //m_bIsCapturing = false; // this is set externally here

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = OpenMediaSource(pSource); // also creates the reader


    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pReader->GetCurrentMediaType(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            &pType
            );
    }


    // Create the sink writer 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(
            pwszFileName,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &m_pWriter
            );
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = ConfigureEncoder(params, pType, m_pWriter, &sink_stream);


    // kick off the recording
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {

        m_llBaseTime = 0;
        m_bIsCapturing = TRUE;

        hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
            (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
            0,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
            );


    }



    SafeRelease(&pType);
    SafeRelease(&pSource);
    pType = NULL;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
    return hr;
}
```

The OpenMediaSource method is here:

```
HRESULT WinCapture::OpenMediaSource(IMFMediaSource *pSource)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IMFAttributes *pAttributes = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 2);


    // use a callback
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, this);
    }

    // set the desired format type
    DWORD dwFormatIndex = (DWORD)formatIdx;

    IMFPresentationDescriptor *pPD = NULL;
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSD = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler *pHandler = NULL;
    IMFMediaType *pType = NULL;

    // create the source reader
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(
            pSource,
            pAttributes,
            &m_pReader
            );
    }

    // steps to set the selected format type
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) hr = pSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pPD);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    BOOL fSelected;
    hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(0, &fSelected, &pSD);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pSD->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(dwFormatIndex, &pType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    // get available framerates
    hr = MFGetAttributeRatio(pType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, &frameRate, &denominator);
    std::cout << "frameRate " << frameRate << "   denominator " << denominator << std::endl;


    hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
        NULL,
        pType
        );

    // set to maximum framerate?
    hr = pHandler->GetCurrentMediaType(&pType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    goto done;

done:
    SafeRelease(&pPD);
    SafeRelease(&pSD);
    SafeRelease(&pHandler);
    SafeRelease(&pType);
    SafeRelease(&pAttributes);
    return hr;
}
```

Here, `formatIdx` is a field of this class that get sets by the user via the GUI. I leave it 0 in order to test. So, I don't think I am missing any steps to get the camera going, but maybe I am.

When I inspect what applications are using the webcam ([using this method](http://lifehacker.com/find-out-what-windows-program-is-using-your-webcam-on-w-1582372561)) after the call to ActivateObject, I see that my application is using the webcam as expected. But, when I enter the callback routine, I see there are two instances of my application using the webcam. This is the same using a blocking method.

I don't know if that is good or bad, but when I enter my callback method:

```
HRESULT WinCapture::OnReadSample(
    HRESULT hrStatus,
    DWORD /*dwStreamIndex*/,
    DWORD /*dwStreamFlags*/,
    LONGLONG llTimeStamp,
    IMFSample *pSample      // Can be NULL
    )
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_critsec);

    if (!IsCapturing() || m_bIsCapturing == false)
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if (FAILED(hrStatus))
    {
        hr = hrStatus;
        goto done;
    }

    if (pSample)
    {
        if (m_bFirstSample)
        {
            m_llBaseTime = llTimeStamp;
            m_bFirstSample = FALSE;
        }

        // rebase the time stamp
        llTimeStamp -= m_llBaseTime;

        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(llTimeStamp);

        if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

        hr = m_pWriter->WriteSample(0, pSample);

        if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }
    }

    // Read another sample.
    hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
        0,
        NULL,   // actual
        NULL,   // flags
        NULL,   // timestamp
        NULL    // sample
        );

done:
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        //NotifyError(hr);
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critsec);
    return hr;
}
```

hrStatus is the 0x00d3704 error I was getting before, and the callback goes straight to `done` thus killing the callbacks.

Finally, I should say that I am modeling (read, 'copying') my code from the example MFCaptureToFile in the Windows SDK Samples and that doesn't work either. Although, there I get this weird negative number for the failed HRESULT: -1072875772.

Comment: The error [0xC00D3704]: "Hardware MFT failed to start streaming due to lack of hardware resources"   MF_E_HW_MFT_FAILED_START_STREAMING defined in mferror.h

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! Do you suppose there is a call I am missing to activate the camera resources? I am using Qt as a GUI backend, and I do call QCameraInfo::availableCameras() to get the initial list of available cameras into the GUI, but I don't touch them after that.

Comment: not sure.  I would stick with MFEnumDeviceSources to enumerate your capture devices (both video and audio).  Then you can easily activate it and get each of its native media types (IMFSourceReader::GetNativeMediaType).

Comment: I now have it so Qt doesn't touch the camera at all as you suggested and the problem persists. One thing I found out is that when I run my record loop (which is on its own thread) I see that two processes on my system have the camera (using this method http://lifehacker.com/find-out-what-windows-program-is-using-your-webcam-on-w-1582372561). I wonder if that is the cause of the problem. I have tried writing this application with callbacks, but am having trouble with using the MFSourceReaderCallBackClass: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998380/imfsourcereadercallback-base-class-undefined

Comment: I should add that the record process is on its own separate thread through all of this. Don't know if that was clear or not.

Comment: You wrote that you use separated thread for running of record loop, but what about COM apartment. Media Foundation is a STA. It means that all calls of methods and function must be executed in context of main thread of application.

Comment: This is getting interesting. I tried initializing the COM library by calling CoInitializeEx with the COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag and it failed saying: `Cannot change thread mode after it is set`. Is it really true that I can't use my MFSourceReader object on a separate thread? The application is singe-threaded anyway.

Comment: I also tried calling CoInitializeEx on the recording thread to no avail.

Comment: So, Is it really true that I can't use my MFSourceReader object on a separate thread? - I think you can't . Conception of STA considers using only one thread for interaction with outer environment of COM object. Of course, it is possible to create many threads INSIDE of STA COM object. More over, by attribute MF_SOURCE_READER_ASYNC_CALLBACK source creates inner pool of threads via MFAllocateWorkQueue function. And interface IMFSourceReaderCallback is called from that pool of threads. The same pool is used by Hardware MFT.

Comment: I could advise my article "CaptureManager" on "CodeProject". It use Media Foundation and includes many workable examples on C#, Python, QtMinGW, WindowsStore, YouTube.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115468/discussion-between-evgeny-pereguda-and-dmedine).

Answer (score -2):

If you have got error [0xC00D3704] - it means that source does not initialized. Such error can be caused by mistake of initialization, busy camera by another application (process) or unsupport of the camera by UVC driver(old cameras support DirectShow driver with partly compatibleness with UVC. It is possible read some general info from old cameras via UVC as friendly name, symbolic link. However, old cameras support DirectShow models - PUSH, while camera pushes bytes into the pipeline, while Media Foundation PULL data - sends special signal and wait data). 
For checking your code I would like advise to research articles about capturing video from web cam on site "CodeProject" - search "videoInput" name.

Comment: I do agree that the device is not properly activated (as that code is not included), but all of this PUSH / PULL stuff is simply misleading (as well as your comments on the COM threading apartment model).